# $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$ and $\alpha\gamma=\gamma\alpha$ implies $\beta\gamma=\gamma\beta$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in S_5$ be. Is it ture that if $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$ and $\alpha\gamma=\gamma\alpha$ then $\beta\gamma=\gamma\beta$?

I think it is not true in general, but I couldn't find any counter example. Could any one can help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\alpha = (12), \beta = (34), \gamma = (35)$, it should be a counterexample!

Comment: Great answer. As an observation, you could even take $\alpha$ as the identity and make this work within $S_3$. If $\alpha$ has to be a non-identity element, then take it as the other element in $C_2$ then within the direct product $C_2 \times G$, $\alpha \times 1$ will commute with all the elements $1\times g$ for $g\in G$, and this answer realises that within $S_5$.